# Extrapolate a line beyond two known points

Tags: java, opengl

I really suck at math. No, better explanation: I don't know how to interpret mathematical notation. My brain just cant interpret it. That's why I come to the programming community for help "translating" math into a language I do understand.

I have two sets of coordinates in 3d space representing the line of sight.

```
Vector1(eyes) x=10 y=10 z=4
Vector2(lookingat) x=10 y=8 z=4.785
```

How do I calculate a point with these double values beyond the looking at value? for example, what lies 2 points beyond the line we are looking it? what location in space would that be?

**In short:**

How do I extrapolate a given point beyond the line made up by two vectors with given double value along the line.

```
a known
 \
  \
   \
    b known
     ?    
      ?     + 3
       ?
        c what is this value...
```

**Edit**

With the help of the answer of @Thrustmaster I came up with this wonderfull solution. Thanks a lot :D

```
private Vec3 calculateLine(Vec3 x1, Vec3 x2, double distance) {
    double length = Math.sqrt(multiply(x2.xCoord - x1.xCoord) + multiply((x2.yCoord - x1.yCoord)) + multiply((x2.zCoord - x1.zCoord)));
    double unitSlopeX = (x2.xCoord-x1.xCoord) / length;
    double unitSlopeY = (x2.yCoord-x1.yCoord) / length;
    double unitSlopeZ = (x2.zCoord-x1.zCoord) / length;
    double x = x1.xCoord + unitSlopeX * distance;
    double y = x1.yCoord + unitSlopeY * distance;
    double z = x1.zCoord + unitSlopeZ * distance;
    return Vec3.createVectorHelper(x, y, x);
}
private double multiply(double one) {
    return one * one;
}
```

Comment: you need this fix: return Vec3.createVectorHelper(x, y, z);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to start looking to basic 3D coordinate geometry.

In 3D, the equation can be written as:

```
x = x1 + unitSlopeX * distance
y = y1 + unitSlopeY * distance
z = z1 + unitSlopeZ * distance
```

.. where (x1,y1,z1) can be any point on the line; in this case (10,10,4).

Next set of unknowns is all 3 unitSlopes. To calculate it, simply subtract the two points (this will ive you a vector), and divide by the length of the vector.

```
length = sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2)
unitSlopeX = (x2-x1) / length
unitSlopeY = (y2-y1) / length
unitSlopeZ = (z2-z1) / length
```

Now, to finally, get your third coordinate, simply plug in distance (any value) into the three equations at the beginning of this post.

---

In vector notation:

```
V = V1 + t * (V2 - V1) / | V2 - V1 |
```

.. where `t` is any real number.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just a beginning 3d programmer, and all I've worked on before was simple intrepolation which has much more examples on the web. The extrapolation bit stumped me but this will help me greatly.
Do you happen to know any resources where they explain it kinda in the way you did it? with a "normal" math example? i'm really interested in these things to learn them.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I dont know of any resources. I'd recommend picking up coordinate geometry books. May be you can start from 2D, most of the concepts in this area can be simply extended to 3D. For instance, the above 3 equations are called "parametric equations of a 3D line" and are simple extensions of that of 2D lines.

Comment: You gave me something to google on ;-) thats equally good. here, have an upvote :D